# Prevent image flickr when loading webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I prevent an image flickr while the page loads for the 1st time.

(Flash of unstyled content)

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#content').hide(); // This content area contains the images
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $('#content').show();
});
```

However, I still see the flickr of images

Comment: Don't hide the content on `document.ready`. Hide the `#content` with inline css. `<div id="content" style="display:none;">...`. Then leave the `window.load`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the html is being rendered before jquery's .ready() function executes because .ready() executes after the page and all the html has been loaded.

You can solve your issue by styling #content in the CSS stylesheet and removing the .hide() from .ready()

```
#content {
    display:none;
}
```

Information regarding .ready() and .load():

> $('document').ready runs the code when the DOM is ready, but not when
>   the page itself has loaded, that is, the site has not been painted and
>   content like images have not been loaded.
>
> $(window).load runs the code when the page has been painted and all
>   content has been loaded. This can be helpful when you need to get the
>   size of an image. If the image has no style or width/height, you can't
>   get its size unless you use $(window).load.